# How to render SKBitmap in Windows.Forms application?

Tags: winforms, skia, skiasharp

Hi I started a new project and WinForms is new for me. I have a SKBitmap object and I don't know how can I render it.

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways. The first thing to do is to install the SkiaSharp.Views package - a small package that contains platform specific views and utilities for converting SkiaSharp types into the current platform types:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp.Views/

After installing you should get theses types:

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/SkiaSharp.Views.Desktop/

Back to the code, you can either add a `SKControl` and draw the bitmap on the paint event:

```
control.PaintSurface += (...) => {
    // draw
};
```

Or, you can convert the bitmap into a Windows bitmap:

```
var sysBitmap = skBitmap.ToBitmap();
```

Then, you can just assign it to a `PictureBox`:

```
pictureBox.Image = sysBitmap;
```